# Is there simpler way than scraping flightradar to determine Number of Flights between Two Countries?

Tags: commercial-aviation, international, flight-schedules

Is there a simple way to procedurally determine how many flights are flown between two countries on a given day?  Maybe even get an inbound/outbound break down?

I consulted the FAA data site (https://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation_data_statistics/) but I didn't find anything promising.  I was also considering scraping flight radar (https://www.flightradar24.com/) but is a somewhat complicated endeavor.  Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: resources location is off topic as defined by the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'd better ask "how many flight cross a border between country X and country Y?". The answers are likely to give you a further readings and links to resources you want.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! One easy but possibly not cheap option is to buy the data from a specialized research company. High quality data is valuable and it takes effort to gather and maintain it.

Comment: You could try sites like Kayak.com and see what's being offered for sale between countries.  Not sure if all airlines would be shown there, but it's a start.  Could be just as tedious as other means as the search is airport to airport, but some countries don't have that many international airports to select from for larger commercial flights.  And some do have a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ADS-B Exchange](https://www.adsbexchange.com/) could be an alternative to FlightRadar24. They have (free if you host a feeder station) APIs so you wouldn't need to go through the headache of scraping. The data should be comparable and with ADS-B becoming mandatory in more and more regions (US since the beginning of the year and an EU mandate covering pretty much all business flights coming in June) you should be able to track anything but small VFR only aircraft.

Comment: Oh this looks very promising! I think I'm going to start by querying airline websites but this seems like a better long term solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and for many countries there's really no way at all.

For example within the EU you could fly your Cessna between Germany and say Denmark and never get recorded anywhere that's publicly available.

Nothing on sites like Flightradar24 (at least not reliably), no official records except for your payment of landing fees using your credit card (then again, if you pay cash...).

I'm sure the same is true between some other groups of countries. And then there are countries where the border and airspace are so porous it's quite possible to get in and out without being noticed illegally. Think smuggling fligths somewhere in Africa or South America. No radar coverage, bush strips that officially don't even exist.

And those flights can make it into the USA as well (drugs runners from Colombia sometimes use aircraft and try to sneak through the US border patrol, navy, and coast guard radar pickets, some no doubt make it.